# Lost Monero Coins but have seed words

Tags: mnemonic-seed

Back early 2018 I installed monero full node with intention to learn to mine, then actually purchased 7 coins. I wrote down the 25 words, but was too smart for my own good with the other passkey info. I wrote it in a way that I have info, but I basically know the info is incorrect. All I can guarantee is the date I opened the wallet, and the 25 words. This was pre ledger. I today installed GUI to a new computer, and tied wallet to ledger. I now have a synced wallet, but balance and history are both 0. The actually computer that was running the node was scrubbed. Have I lost my coins?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the 25 words you can restore the wallet and recover the coins.  I'd do this on a PC and not a ledger at first. (Find the money then move to a ledger if desired)  The wallet has to fully sync to a fully synced daemon/node. If restoring by date/height make sure its a bit before that. or just do a full refresh.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I tried that. and had the same issue. How can I remove all that i have done so far from my computer (GUI wallet, daemon etc), that I can try again without ledger?

Comment: On a Mac/Linux delete the ~/.bitmonero folder (blockchain). And whatever folder the wallet is in.  Not sure in Windows land.  I know Monero at least used to put in some registry keys.  You could just make a VM, install monero, (I'd suggest just the CLI, but thats me. --restore-deterimistic I think is the flag.) and do the restore.  It should complain about no daemon.  Then I'd just have it point to a remote node for the daemon (most pools offer them). Good luck.

Comment: Hi Dave, Rather than try deleting, I downloaded from getmonero.org the GUI zip file to a new computer. I dont know how to use the Monero CLI, so I tried simple mode wallet, typed the seed words single spaced,, and put height date 2 months before I started in 2018. I got exactly the same message as the first computer. "Electrum style word list failed verification". I KNOW the words are correct, I triple checked them at the time, and have cross referenced them against the Monero list of words for spelling. I have also tried this words to start with mymonero.com. Same result. What can I do now??

Comment: By any chance did you transpose any of the words 'for security'?  The last word is a checksum and I believe should also be one of the other words. (Windows, Mac, or Linux?  Not that this would be the prob but might be able to write a small script if Mac/Linux to help)

Comment: You said this is all pre-ledger.  Sure of that?  Could those 25 words be Ledger words?

Comment: Hi Dave. I didnt write any word for security. I do have three other pieces of information, one is what I presume is a password. One is also possibly another password, the othe says loc: 00000  (a five digit number) I am certain this was pre ledger, I remember being pissed at the time that Monero kept talking about integrating ledger, but nothing happening. I actually have my cold wallet seed and other info stored on a monero.how branded paper thing.

Comment: I think also, ledger is 24 words?

Comment: I'm at a loss.  The 25 words should restore it.  I've restored a bunch of times.  For grins, maybe an older version?  Like 0.15?  If that works you should be OK to upgrade.  Might be some odd bug in the restore feature?  I dunno.  Grasping at straws here.  If you find the solution, let us know!

Comment: Hi Dave. One of the pieces of info I had twigged to me. I had changed the seed word order. Now, with the new seed order, I can open a mymonero.org wallet, but balance is 0. I tried with Monero GUI, entered new seed to GUI, with backdated height, but it now refuses to go furtjer than "next" any ideas? A clean reinstall without ledger influences? Problem with that is I get the same "no progress" on the second computer. Both are running daemons, the second computer actually has not activated a wallet yet.

Comment: Updated: SOLVED. Was out of sequence seed. Thanks all for your help :)

Comment: Awesome!!  Glad to see you didn't lose 'em.  That's also why I asked if you transposed them.

Comment: I've done nothing constructive yet  looking at the GUI and feeling satisfied 